# How to use DELETE with EXCEPT clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to do some ETL from some single tenant DBs (per client) to a multi-tenant DB (all clients, or "global").  In the global DB, I'm trying to maintain a lookup table that identifies users that are associated with a client.  So I have this:

```
Database: Global
Tables: Users and ClientUsers

Database: Client
Tables: Users
```

After some other ETL operations, I want to clean up the ClientUsers table by deleting any Users that no longer exist in the Client.Users table.  I thought this would work:

```
DECLARE @ClientID varchar = 'ClientA'

DELETE FROM Global.dto.ClientUsers
SELECT ClientID, UserID FROM Global.dto.ClientUsers WHERE ClientID=@ClientID
EXCEPT
SELECT ClientID=@ClientID, UserID FROM ClientA_DB.dbo.Users
```

But this deletes ALL records.  I tested the individual select statements, and they return what I expect for my first test, where there are none to delete.  Both select statements return the exact same dataset.  Which to me means that no records should be deleted.  Right?  Apparently, I'm missing some basic understanding or a nuance as to how EXISTS works, because this seems like it should be straightforward!

I realize its possible to do this using other methods, but I'm stumped why EXCEPT doesn't work like I think it should.

Comment: Do you mean to ask why EXCEPT doesn't work like you think it should?

Comment: I believe the issue is that `Delete From TABLE` is one complete statement.  Your `Select ....` following it is a separate statement.

Comment: Doh, yes I meant EXCEPT...  Editing question now...

Comment: I think @APH has the answer.

Comment: Yea, duh...  So if I would just look at the "Messages" tab, I would have got that clue:  (1717 row(s) affected)  (0 row(s) affected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it isn't working is that you're actually running two statements sequentially.  Think of your code more like:

```
DECLARE @ClientID varchar = 'ClientA'

DELETE FROM Global.dto.ClientUsers;

SELECT ClientID, UserID FROM Global.dto.ClientUsers WHERE ClientID=@ClientID
EXCEPT
SELECT ClientID=@ClientID, UserID FROM ClientA_DB.dbo.Users;
```

If you want to modify the `Delete` statement, you need to follow it with a `Where`, `Join`, etc.

For some alternative methods to get the result you want, see the excellent answers at:
[Using T-SQL EXCEPT with DELETE / Optimizing a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43143404/using-t-sql-except-with-delete-optimizing-a-query)

Comment: Yes I saw that post, and the accepted answer didn't really answer the question (EXCEPT not EXISTS).  It did however offer an alternative.

Comment: could wrap it in a cte perhaps?

Comment: I agree, that's why I didn't flag this as duplicate.  I did want to link to the solution in order to help future users with the same question, though.

Comment: I got tripped up here because it worked with my INSERT.  DELETE behaves differently!

Comment: @scsimon - doesn't look like a CTE will work...  Can't delete from the cte 'because it contains aggregates'